# Check next string in the list

Tags: c#

Trying to figure out how to check the next string vs. the current string in a loop (pseudo code):

```
string currentName = string.Empty;

for(int i=0; i < SomeList.Count; i++)
{
    currentName = SomeList[i].Name;

    //do some other logic here

    if(string.Compare(SomeList[i].Name, SomeList[i+1].Name) == 0)
         // do something
}
```

this does not seem to work:

```
if(string.Compare(SomeList[i].Name, SomeList[i+1].Name)
```

I want to see if the current string is the same as what the next string in the loop before it gets to the next iteration in the loop.

Comment: 1) What's wrong with `SomeList[i].Name == SomeList[i+1].Name`? 2) How should the last element be handled?

Comment: It should be work in list. Better you check current value with previous value and seperate case for first element, so you can implement logic when duplicate name comes.

Comment: maybe the next item in the list is an outOfBound element?

Comment: i+1 works until last object (When +1 does not exist)?

Answer (score 3):

You are close. You will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when you get to the last element because you are attempting to check the following element (inherently, there is none).

Just change

```
for(int i=0; i < SomeList.Count(); i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i < SomeList.Count() - 1; i++)
```

Comment: i = SomeList.Count() ; i >= 0 ; i--

Comment: Yes, but doing this you'll never get to the last element (eg: the `//do some other logic here` part)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, isn't it? You have to watch your boundary case at the upper end:

```
if (i != SomeList.Count - 1 && 
    string.Compare(SomeList[i].Name, SomeList[i+1].Name) == 0) 
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you bump the index counter to start at 1, and do the comparison to SomeList[i-1], SomeList[i] so that you don't get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Also, this is case sensitive matching, call the `ToUpper()` method to ensure to do case insensitive matching.

Comment: Or you could just use `String.Compare(x, y, true)`;